# How to recieve not all fields from related(ForeignKey) django model using 'select_related'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

#### Env:

python >= 3.6 
Django >=2.1.0

#### Models example:

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    a_field = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="example")


class B(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    b_field = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="example")
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="b", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#### Question:

How I can fetch only required fields from related models using [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

#### How it could be done with [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
prefetch_obj = Prefetch("a", queryset=A.objects.only("id", "a_field"))
B.objects.only("id", "b_field", "a").prefetch_related(prefetch_obj)
```

But it produces 2 request to DB due to `prefetch_related` using.

```
SELECT `main_b`.`id`, `main_b`.`b_field`, `main_b`.`a_id` FROM `main_b`  LIMIT 21; args=()
SELECT `main_a`.`id`, `main_a`.`a_field` FROM `main_a` WHERE `main_a`.`id` IN (1); args=(1,)
```

If I use `select_related` it makes 1 DB call, but fetches all fields from `A` model:

```
models.B.objects.only("id", "b_field", "a").select_related("a")

SELECT `main_b`.`id`, `main_b`.`b_field`, `main_b`.`a_id`, `main_a`.`id`, `main_a`.`a_field`, `main_a`.`a_not_required_field` FROM `main_b` INNER JOIN `main_a` ON (`main_b`.`a_id` = `main_a`.`id`)  LIMIT 21; args=()
```

Comment: check this [Selecting specific fields using select_related in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524259/selecting-specific-fields-using-select-related-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.select_related('related_obj').only('related_obj__field')`. Please see the docs on [Only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#only).